# iMac kernel panics during sleep

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, kernel-panic

Two weeks, my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) started having kernel panics during sleep, effectively turning itself off (With all unsaved data lost, etc) and on while sleeping. I attached [one of the crash reports](https://gist.github.com/LIJI32/77593f5c32d63e0e79ee5344dfb434f3), although I can't seem to find anything relevant in there. Can anybody tell what is the source of the problem and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately the Crash report is not helpful. Is 'Enable Power Nap' active? (see here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202824)

Comment: It is, but disabling it will probably only work around the problem; I'd rather have the problem itself fixed.

Comment: I didn't suggested that and that's not the point - it just answered a question if there is (scheduled) activity during sleep mode. A fact you have not mentioned in your description of the problem and imho a very important one.

Comment: Just wanted to make that clear, I didn't assume you'd actually suggest so. In any case, other than power nap being enabled, there's no other scheduled activity during sleep.